# Configure Apache to hide files of type .json

Tags: apache2, webserver, mime-types

I have some files of type .json on the DocumentRoot of apache. I need to hide or not allow these files to be shown to public viewers when they access using the url. 
http://somehostname/somefile.json, How do I disable this option of not showing these files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy from the rule for .ht files, you can add below lines to your httpd.conf

```
<Files ~ "\.json$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all   
 Satisfy All     
</Files>
```

Comment: Can I access the file from my program or will it say forbidden. ?

Comment: you can still access the file from your program as long as it is readable by the apache server.